# How to connect to local emulator for azure media services development?

Tags: azure, azure-media-services, azure-storage-emulator, azure-emulator

How to get below info  values when we want to connect to LOCAL azure emulator?

My appsettings.json file -

"AadClientId": 
  "AadEndpoint":
  "AadSecret": 
 "AadTenantId": 
  "AccountName": 
 "ArmAadAudience":
 "ArmEndpoint": 
 "Region": 
  "ResourceGroup": 
  "SubscriptionId

Answer (score -1):

Media Services are Azure Only product and there is not an emulator for this. You can create a resource in azure dedicated for development but of course that adds an extra cost.